# Mudar cor de fundo do item seleccionado no NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Como posso mudar a cor de fundo do item seleccionado no NavigationDrawer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#d2191919"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hide Action Bar
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    addListenerOnButton();

    v = mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView();

}
```

Comment: A alteração vai ser feita nos itens da sua lista e não no próprio `ListView`. Coloque mais códigos pra gente poder ver. Por exemplo, como você monta o `adapter`?

Comment: ainda não montei nenhum adapter mas estou a fazer todas as inicializações do `MenuDrawer` no `onCreate`

Comment: Você não tem um layout para "inflar" estes itens dentro do `ListView`?